# Logits and Labels not matching while running image segmentation model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, image-segmentation

I was trying to run the following code:

```
model = sm.Unet('resnet50', encoder_weights='imagenet', classes=n_classes, activation=activation)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 1e-3), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_test, y_test, 
                    batch_size = 1, 
                    verbose=1, 
                    epochs=5, 
                    validation_data=(y_test, y_test), 
                    shuffle=True)
```

I am getting returned the following error:

```
ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((1, 64, 64, 4) vs (1, 64, 64, 1)).
```

I checked, and the shapes of X_train and y_train are (113, 64,64,3) and (133, 64,64,1) respectively.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your code is not complete. you're working on a binary classification task, the number of classes in the output layer of your model should be 1.
Try using:

```
model = sm.Unet('resnet50', encoder_weights='imagenet', classes=1, activation=activation)  # Set classes to 1
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

# Make sure y_test has the same shape as model predictions
y_test = np.expand_dims(y_test, axis=-1)

history = model.fit(X_test, y_test, 
                    batch_size=1, 
                    verbose=1, 
                    epochs=5, 
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),  # Use X_test for validation
                    shuffle=True)
```